# how long a firebase cli token stays functional?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have the following chunk as a part of a recursive delete cloud function , my question is I managed to store the cli token inside fb.token, but how long this token will last ? Is it forever or should have to update it frequently ? , is it even a thing for the user to be able to call this function ? , in my use case , I want to automate the process of deleting user account and his all related collections in one action, and this function really serves me well, not to mention I don’t have to get all docs … so if this stored token fails and deletes gets rejected due to token expiration during production for some reason it could cause big issues in my db structure..

```js
await firebase_tools.firestore.delete(path, {
      project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
      recursive: true,
      yes: true,
      token: functions.config().fb.token,
      force: true,
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how long this token will last ? Is it forever or should have to update it frequently ?

Tokens obtained by `firebase login:ci` doesn't have expiration, though it can be revoked manually. The token is tied to the access privileges of the user and you can check the tokens used in [here](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions).

If you want to use another method, I suggest that you use [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) for authentication. Then, grant any necessary permissions to the `service account` in your project. These permissions depend on the actions that had to be performed by the CLI. You can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access) for further explanation that you must follow.

Comment: My question is About special generated token !! Not the classic user token… it is a token you generate in the firebase cli…. And you can inject it in to cloud functions environment.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli Docs reference for this current token I am asking about.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've updated my answer.